# Python argparse case inconsistency between optional and positional arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I was wondering why the inconsistency between the case-transformation of optional and positional arguments in Python's `argparse`. Adding the `'--optional-argument'` to the parser will be named `'optional_argument'`, but positional argument would stay `positional-argument`.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('positional-argument')
parser.add_argument('--optional-argument')
arg_dict = vars(parser.parse_args('Positional --optional-argument Optional'.split()))
print(arg_dict)
# {'positional-argument': 'Positional', 'optional_argument': 'Optional'}
```

I could change the way I add the positional argument to the parser, but the inconsistency would remain (though at a different place)

```
parser.add_argument('positional_argument')
parser.add_argument('--optional-argument')
# {'positional_argument': 'Positional', 'optional_argument': 'Optional'}
```

Comment: The dash replacement lets you access the value with `args.optional_argument` (with a valid Python attribute name).  You usually have more freedom in choosing the Positionals `dest`.  And if you use a `metavar` your user doesn't even see the `dest` in the `help`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is a known issue.  https://bugs.python.org/issue15125

Suggested workarounds:

- If you use `'positional-argument'`, you can extract it from the namespace using `getattr()`.
- If you use `'positional_argument'`, you can change how it is displayed in the help output with `metavar='positional-argument'`.